# electron-installer-debian compiled app .deb won't run

Tags: electron

My compiled app don't run and i don't know why ...

- electron-installer-debian -> 3.0.0
- node -> 8.16.0
- npm -> 6.4.1
- operating system ->ubuntu 16.04.6 amd64
- I can compile the example app successfully.
- I can compile my app successfully.

**What did i do**

`package.json content`

```
{
"name": "electron-quick-start",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A minimal Electron application",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron .",
  "build": "electron-packager . electron-quick-start --platform linux --arch x64 --out dist/",
  "deb64": "electron-installer-debian --src dist/electron-quick-start-linux-x64/ --dest dist/installers/ --arch amd64"
},
"repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
"keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
  "electron": "^8.2.5",
  "electron-installer-debian": "^3.0.0",
  "electron-packager": "^14.2.1"
  }
}
```

I compile my app successfullt by executing `npm run build` to build my app with electron-packager then i do `npm run deb64` to compile my code.
It return a successfull sentence.

Then i find my `electron-quick-start_1.0.0_amd64.deb` in the `dist/installers` folder and install it successfully (no error of any kind).

**What did you expect to happen?**

I expect to run my app by searching it in the ubuntu search bar.

**What actually happened?**

The app juste don't run. No error pop up. Nothing ... :'(
Even if i try to run it from terminal

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnRJt.png)

Comment: Could you try to run your app by name from terminal, maybe there will be some output with errors

Comment: It don't return anything ...

Answer (score 0):

electron-installer-debian creates dab file which by default installs your app in usr/lib folder. If you navigate to usr/lib//resources/ give permissions to your app folder your app should work, but this is not recommended for security reasons.